# How to create and track a processing chain with docker and python

Tags: python, docker

I'm working on a series of processes that I plan on putting in their own containers.  It's a simple step by step process but I'm not sure what the best way to get data from one container to the next or how to keep track of progress.  Typically I would make activities 2, 3, and 4 separate scripts and import them all into activity 1.  Now each activity will be a separate container and I'm not sure what to do.

Activity 1 - Provide a 2d shape vector.  Pass this to activity 2.
Activity 2 - Download imagery based on shape provided in activity 1.
Activity 3 - Once imagery is downloaded run some analysis.
Activity 4 - Once analysis is done run stats and save information to database.

One thought was to use docker run and entrypoints.  Activity 1 would at some point run activity 2 which would have the python script as an entrypoint.

```
docker run activity2 "inputVectorFromActivity1"
```

Another option would be to use environmental variables

```
docker run activity2 -e INVECTOR="inputVectorFromActivity1"
```

So in these examples Activity 1 would call 2, which would call 3, which would call 4.  That seems logical but I'm not sure it's the best solution.  I also don't see an elegant way to keep track of progress or report errors.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d look into a queueing system, for instance [RabbitMQ](https://rabbitmq.com/).  That would let you have four queues, one for each task, and let you keep track of where things are and have multiple things in each possible state at a time.  You could have four separate long-running containers that all worked off of one of these queues, and if you needed more processing power for, say, the analysis phase, you could launch multiple copies of the container.

As you lay out the problem it doesn’t actually sound overly complex and you should consider the merits of running this in a single process/script/container.  (For instance, the last step of “take data from some disk location and copy it into a database” would probably be easier to merge with earlier steps; if the entire pipeline reduces to “acquire data, process it, and save it” it might be simpler to just not call it a “pipeline”.)

You almost definitely should not make `docker run` or `docker exec` part of your core processing flow.  If you can run either of these Docker commands, you can do literally anything to the host system: there are major security considerations that you’d prefer to not think about.  Depending on your environment there may be some startup costs you’d also prefer to avoid (anything involving a JVM, for instance, still takes ~forever to come up).  A long-running worker container is generally a better model.

Comment: Thanks you very much for that helpful answer.  I'm using this project as an opportunity to get better with docker and process tracking.  It would definitely be easier as a single process!  I'll checkout RabbitMQ.

Comment: Yep, RabbitMQ is perfect for the job.  Thank you!